# Data arrays must have the same length, and match time discretization in dynamic problems error in GEKKO

Tags: arrays, variables, minimization, gekko

I want to find the value of the parameter m that minimizes my variable x subject to a system of differential equations. I have the following code

```
from gekko import GEKKO

def run_model_m(days, population, case, k_val, b_val, u0_val, sigma_val, Kmax0, a_val, c_val):
 list_x =[]
 list_u =[]
 list_Kmax =[]
 for i in range(len(days)):
   list_xi=[]
   list_ui=[]
   list_Ki=[]

  for j in range(len(days[i])):
  #try:
    m = GEKKO(remote=False)
    #m.time= days[i][j]
    eval = np.linspace(days[i][j][0], days[i][j][-1], 100, endpoint=True)
    m.time = eval
    x_data= population[i][j]
  
    variable=  np.linspace(population[i][j][0], population[i][j][-1], 100, endpoint=True)
    x = m.Var(value=population[i][j][0], lb=0)
    sigma= m.Param(sigma_val)
    d = m.Param(c_val)
    k = m.Param(k_val)
    b = m.Param(b_val)
    r = m.Param(a_val)
    step = np.ones(len(eval))
    step= 0.2*step
    step[0]=1
    m_param = m.CV(value=1, lb=0, ub=1, integer=True); m_param.STATUS=1
    u = m.Var(value=u0_val, lb=0, ub=1)
    #m.free(u)
    a = m.Param(a_val)
    c= m.Param(c_val)
    Kmax= m.Param(Kmax0) 

    if case == 'case0':
      m.Equations([x.dt()==  x*(r*(1-x/(Kmax))-m_param/(k+b*u)-d), u.dt()== sigma*(m_param*b/((k+b*u)**2))])
    elif case == 'case4':
      m.Equations([x.dt()==  x*(r*(1-u**2)*(1-x/(Kmax))-m_param/(k+b*u)-d), u.dt() == sigma*(-2*u*r*(1-x/(Kmax))+(b*m_param)/(b*u+k)**2)])
    p = np.zeros(len(eval))
    p[-1] = 1.0
    final = m.Param(value=p)
    m.Obj(x)
    m.options.IMODE = 6
    m.options.MAX_ITER=15000
    m.options.SOLVER=1

    # optimize
    m.solve(disp=False, GUI=False)
    #m.open_folder(dataset_path+'inf')
 
    list_xi.append(x.value)
    list_ui.append(u.value)
    list_Ki.append(m_param.value) 
  
 list_x.append(list_xi)
 list_Kmax.append(list_Ki)
 list_u.append(list_ui)
return list_x, list_u, list_Kmax, m.options.OBJFCNVAL



scaled_days[i][j] =[-7.0, 42.0, 83.0, 125.0, 167.0, 217.0, 258.0, 300.0, 342.0]
scaled_pop[i][j] = [0.01762491277346285, 0.020592540360308997, 0.017870838266697213, 0.01690069378982034,0.015512320147187675,0.01506701796298272,0.014096420738841563,0.013991224004743027,0.010543380664478205]
k0,b0,group, case0,  u0, sigma0, K0, a0, c0 = (100, 20, 'Size3, Inc', 'case0', 0.1, 0.05, 2, 0, 0.01)
list_x2, list_u2, list_Kmax2,final =run_model_m(days=[[scaled_days[i][j]]], population= 
[[scaled_pop[i][j]]],case=case1, k_val=list_b1[i0][0], b_val=b1, u0_val=list_u1[i0][j0], 
sigma_val=sigma1, Kmax0=K1, a_val=list_Kmax1[0][0], c_val=c1)
```

I get the error Data arrays must have the same length, and match time discretization in dynamic problems error but I don't understand why. I have tried making x and m_param arrays, with x=m.Var, m_param =m.MV... But still get the same error, even if they are all arrays of the same length. Is this the right way to find the solution of the minimization problem?

Answer (score 3):

I think the error was just that in run_model_m I was passing a list as u0_val and it didn't have the same dimensions as m.time. So it should be u0_val=list_u1[0][0][0]