# GEKKO ARX Model Forecasting: data arrays must have the same length

Tags: python, time-series, gekko

I am trying to use `sysid` to regress an ARX model periodically, then evaluate the predictive ability of that model by simulating with the future inputs and comparing the output with the experimental data. When I try to solve using `m.solve()` I get the following error: `Exception: Data arrays must have the same length, and match time discretization in dynamic problems`

The following is an MRE:

```
X = [[ 0.9,  0.], [ 0.9, 0.],[ 0.9,0.],[ 0.9,0.],[ 0.9, 0.],[ 0.5,0.],[0.5,0.],[0.5,0.],[0.5,0.], [ 0.5, 0.]] # 2 values for inputs at each time step
Y = [20.3, 20.3, 20.2, 20.2, 20.1, 20.1, 20.1, 20.,  19.9, 19.8,] # 1 output at each time step

t = np.linspace(0, 9*300, 10)  # 10 points 5 minutes apart each

na = 1  # output coefficients
nb = 2  # input coefficients
res, p, K = m.sysid(t, X, Y, na, nb, pred='meas')

m.time = t - t[0]
y_, u_ = m.arx(p)
u_[0].value = X[0]
u_[1].value = X[1]

m.options.imode = 4
m.options.nodes = 2

# simulate
m.solve()
```

I don't want to control, rather apply the experimental values to future timesteps and see how the ARX model extrapolates.

Thanks for your help

Comment: What is `m`? Probably `m=GEKKO()`? **THEN PLEASE ADD YOUR CODE COMPLETELY!**

Comment: Did you [check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65130142/data-arrays-must-have-the-same-length-and-match-time-discretization-in-dynamic)?

Comment: @Shayan, That is my error trying to create a minimum working example from a few nested loops. I have checked that post. My problem is that most vectors appear to be the same length in my debugger. I suspect I need to modify `y-` but I'm not sure how as I want to solve for it, not manipulate it or assign values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with this section and how the data is loaded into `value`:

```py
u_[0].value = X[:,0]
u_[1].value = X[:,1]
y_[0].value = Y
```

Try printing `X[0]` and `X[1]` to see that they are only the first and second elements of the original list. Converting to a numpy array helps with the slicing.

```py
import numpy as np
from gekko import GEKKO

m = GEKKO()

X = np.array([[ 0.9,  0.], [ 0.9, 0.],\
     [ 0.9,0.],[ 0.9,0.],\
     [ 0.9, 0.],[ 0.5,0.],\
     [0.5,0.],[0.5,0.],\
     [0.5,0.], [ 0.5, 0.]]) # 2 values for inputs at each time step
Y = np.array([20.3, 20.3, 20.2, 20.2,\
     20.1, 20.1, 20.1, 20., \
     19.9, 19.8]) # 1 output at each time step

t = np.linspace(0, 9*300, 10)  # 10 points 5 minutes apart each

na = 1  # output coefficients
nb = 2  # input coefficients
res, p, K = m.sysid(t, X, Y, na, nb, pred='meas')

m.time = t - t[0]
y_, u_ = m.arx(p)
u_[0].value = X[:,0]
u_[1].value = X[:,1]
y_[0].value = Y

print(X[0])
print(X[1])

m.options.imode = 4
m.options.nodes = 2

# simulate
m.solve()
```

Here is another example with Pandas DataFrames:

[image: system identification]

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# load data and parse into columns
url = 'http://apmonitor.com/do/uploads/Main/tclab_dyn_data2.txt'
data = pd.read_csv(url)
t = data['Time']
u = data[['H1','H2']]
y = data['T1']

# generate time-series model
m = GEKKO(remote=False) # remote=True for MacOS

# system identification
na = 2 # output coefficients
nb = 2 # input coefficients
yp,p,K = m.sysid(t,u,y,na,nb,diaglevel=1)

plt.figure()
plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.plot(t,u)
plt.legend([r'$u_0$',r'$u_1$'])
plt.ylabel('MVs')
plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.plot(t,y)
plt.plot(t,yp)
plt.legend([r'$y_0$',r'$z_0$'])
plt.ylabel('CVs')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.savefig('sysid.png')
plt.show()
```

We're also working on a package with a [Seeq add-on for system identification](https://github.com/BYU-PRISM/Seeq) that runs in Python and Jupyter notebooks.

Comment: Thanks! It all came down to the dimensions of X and Y and understanding that better!